# my python does not work " -bash: */python: Invalid argument"

Tags: python

Suddenly my development server python does not work.
Error message is as follows:

```
root@scu4:~# python
-bash: /root/anaconda3/bin/python: Invalid argument
```

`/root/anaconda3/bin/` is python installed directory.

How can I fix it?

Comment: python should link to python3 as a symlink anyway

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6753

Answer (score 1):

this error is because its not opening python from directory in which its installed rather its opening from /root/anaconda3/bin/python and it requires some arguements. 
you can try `python -h` or `python --help`

there can be a chance that after installing anaconda it might have upgraded to python 3.x version try

```
root@scu4:~#python3
```

might solve your problem.

If this doesnt help, sudo root and then run the following command : `ls -lah /usr/bin | grep python` it should produce some output if not python is relocated to someother directory.

Comment: I tried "python -h", it returned me same results,
    root@scu4:~# python -h
    -bash: /root/anaconda3/bin/python: Invalid argument
    root@scu4:~# python --help
    -bash: /root/anaconda3/bin/python: Invalid argument

Comment: and ls -las / usr/bin | grep python -- returns me like as follows, 

root@scu4:~# ls -lah /usr/bin | grep python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Aug 20 17:12 pdb3.6 -> ../lib/python3.6/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31 Oct 25  2018 py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      9 Oct 25  2018 python3 -> python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4.4M Aug 20 17:12 python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4.4M Aug 20 17:12 python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     10 Oct 25  2018 python3m -> python3.6m

Comment: You can see `->` means that there s symbolic link created to normal python commands, thats why your python isnt running. try `python3.6` might solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If Anaconda is on docker stop the docker and start it again.

```
docker stop <container>
docker start <container>
docker attach <continer>
```

See [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8305) issue for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

helped me.